# Sending data from Android App to PHP with JSON is not working

Tags: php, android, json

We are making a project voor School and we have some problems with sending data from our Android App to our PHP-controller.

First of all :

here is the code :
First of all , almost the full Code of our AddScoreActivity

```
public static String POST(String url,ScoreData score){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("Totaal", score.getTotaleScore());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Strikes",score.getAantalStrikes());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Spare",score.getAantalSpares());
        jsonObject.accumulate("Game_ID",3);
        jsonObject.accumulate("Google_ID",3);

        json = jsonObject.toString();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Did not work!";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Inputstream", e.getLocalizedMessage());

    }

    return result;

}
```

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

```
    TotaleScore = editTotaleScore.getText().toString();
    AantalStrikes = editAantalStrikes.getText().toString();
    AantalSpares = editAantalspares.getText().toString();

    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.submitScoreButton:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Enter some data!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/ICTProjects3/ScoreController");
            break;
    }

}



private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        score = new ScoreData();

        score.setTotaleScore(TotaleScore);
        score.setAantalStrikes(AantalStrikes);
        score.setAantalSpares(AantalSpares);

        return POST(urls[0],score);
    }

 private boolean validate(){
    if(editTotaleScore.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(editAantalStrikes.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(editAantalspares.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader((inputStream)));
    String line = "";
    String result = "" ;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();;
    return result;
}
```

I think this is working well. If i'm using my Android Emulator & looking to fiddler. My emulator is sending this to my PHP-controller :

```
POST http://localhost/ICTProjects3/ScoreController HTTP/1.1 Accept:
  application/json Content-type: application/json Content-Length: 85
  Host: localhost Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent:
  Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

 {"scoreTotaal":"5","scoreStrikes":"55","scoreSpares":"555","Game_ID":3,"Google_ID":3}
```

Problem is. Its doing nothing. I can't add it to my database with my Controller. Its not a problem with my methode : ScoreToevoegen($aScoreData). Thats for putting it into my database. Its working webbased so normally it would work here. 
This is my PHP-controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['json']))
    {
        $aJson = $_POST['json'];
        $aScoreData = json_decode($aJson, true);

        $this->load->model('Score_model');
        $this->Score_model->ScoreToevoegen($aScoreData); // Inserting it in the database.

    }
```

I really hope you guys can help me. I'm stuck on this moment.
Thank you!

EDIT : ScoreToevoegen-Method & also the Controller for webbased (that is working!). It's made with CodeIgniter

ScoreController.PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST['UploadScore'])){
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('ScoreView', $data);
        }
        else {
            $aScoreData =[
                //'Game_ID' => $this->input->post('gameID'),
                //'Google_ID' => $this->input->post('googleID'),
                'Game_ID' =>2,
                'Google_ID' =>2,
                'Totaal' => $this->input->post('scoreTotaal'),
                'Strikes' => $this->input->post('scoreSpares'),
                'Spare' => $this->input->post('scoreStrikes')
            ];
        $this->load->model('Score_model');
        $this->Score_model->ScoreToevoegen($aScoreData);

        $this->load->view('ScoreView', $data);
    }}
```

Score_Model.PHP

```
       public function ScoreToevoegen($aData)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('score', $aData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending JSON data as request body, and $_POST['something'] is for fetching data from a posted form.

Instead of this:

```
if (isset($_POST['json']))
```

You should use something like this:

```
$aScoreData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ($aScoreData) {
    $this->load->model('Score_model');
    $this->Score_model->ScoreToevoegen($aScoreData);
}
```

Comment: Check what's in $aScoreData with var_dump. If that's empty or false, dump content of php://input, and if that's empty, dump $_post superglobal

Answer (score 0):

I this there is a problem in you ScoreToevoegen($aScoreData) method. Can you paste your function code. There must be problem in connectivity with the MySQL.

Comment: I added it to my post. But that can't be the problem , its to small & for webbased it is working.